# logstash individual log parse with multi line

Tags: filter, multiline, logstash

I have a set of log file which each file log is for specific machine.

What i am trying to achieve is to use the `multiline{}` filter to join the multi-line messages in each of the file because i would like to have a single `@timestamp` for each file.

example data in the log file

> title
>
> description
>
> test1
>
> test pass
>
> test end

```
 filter {
  multiline {
    pattern => "from_start_line to end of line"
    what => "previous"
    negate => true
  }
}
```

I just want to make all the data in the log file as single event without using the pattern.

pretty much like telling logstash to make a multi-line event until `EOF`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do like that. Because logstash will always keep monitoring the file. Therefore the EOF is meaningless for it.

The other way you can do is add some pattern to the end of the logs. For example, add `log_end` to the end of each log output.

```
title

description

test1

test pass

test end-log_end
```

Then you can use this pattern to multiline all the logs.

```
 multiline {
     pattern => "log_end$"
     negate => true
     what => "next"
 }
```

Hope this can help you.

Comment: I only know that i can replace the message content by mutate {gsub => ['message', "any word", "word to replace"]} before the multiline but how to add log_end only at the last line as you suggested?

Comment: I means you have to add your program/code which output the logs.

Comment: i only have the access to the log, guess thats mean i need to download all the log from the server and use c++/python script to append the pattern into the log before feeding it to logstash. =/